# How to get data from combobox from datagrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have been looking for a way to get data out from this datagrid combobox that i made. Specifically the selected value of every combobox from columns. I am new to WPF and would be really grateful if someone would help.

Thanks

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="tb" Margin="5,51,5,5" ItemsSource="{Binding}"         AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Include" Binding="{Binding Include}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Measure" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Measure}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

C#:

```
ObservableCollection<State> items = new ObservableCollection<State>();
        foreach (string col in columns)
        {
            items.Add(new State()
            {
                Name = col,
                Include = true,
                Measure = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Sum", "Average" }
            });
        }
        DataContext = items;
```

Picture of the columns:

[image]

Comment: For what purpose do you need combobox items? In wpf we are using bindings, so that you **never** have to get something from view. Why not using `DataGridComboBoxColumn` btw?

Comment: No particular reason to use combobox. I just need user input from dropbox like input for specific columns. How do you use `DataGridComboBoxColumn` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing stuff. I assume you want your State items to have a `string` Measure property, and not a collection of them, but you want to be able to select the Measure value from a Combo with several options...

If that's the case, then you should redefine your Measure property to be a single string, and not a collection.

```
ObservableCollection<State> items = new ObservableCollection<State>();
    foreach (string col in columns)
    {
        items.Add(new State()
        {
            Name = col,
            Include = true,
            Measure = string.Empty  // Initialize it to whatever you want
        });
    }
    DataContext = items;
```

Then create the Measure values collection somewhere else in your DataContext, or if you don't have a DataContext other than your collection, you can define it in XAML.

And, finally, in your DataGrid you must bind both the ItemsSource and the SelectedItem properties of your Combos. They'll share the same ItemsSource, which must be fetched from wherever you put the collection, instead of the row's DataContext:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="tb" Margin="5,51,5,5" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <!-- This is where the values are defined -->
        <col:ArrayList x:Key="MeasureValues">
            <sys:String>Sum</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Average</sys:String>
        </col:ArrayList>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Include" Binding="{Binding Include}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Measure" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox Margin="2"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Measure}"
                              ItemsSource="{StaticResource MeasureValues}" />
                              <!-- And this is where you consume those values -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If you don't wanna put the values in XAML, you'll have to define the collection in another DataContext and create a Binding to it somehow (using RelativeSource, ElementName and stuff like that).

This works with a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, too, of course:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="tb" Margin="5,51,5,5" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <!-- This is where the values are defined -->
        <col:ArrayList x:Key="MeasureValues">
            <sys:String>Sum</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Average</sys:String>
        </col:ArrayList>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Include" Binding="{Binding Include}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Measure" Width="*"
                                SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Measure}"
                                ItemsSource="{StaticResource MeasureValues}" />
                                <!-- And this is where you consume those values -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Mmmh, just saw that you're using the items collection as DataContext... I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Is there any chance that you could show example how the actual data fetching works? I am kinda lost with this one.

Comment: In my example, with the Measure values collection defined in XAML, it should work fine just as I wrote it. Or do you want to use DataBinding instead?

Comment: I'll edit the answer to include the collection in the DataGrid piece of code, to make it clearer.